# Creating a Grid below current background

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I'm not sure how to add a grid below the current background picture and continue adding info. When I try adding a grid now, it just creates one below the navbar and not below the current background.

```css
/**********BODY GENERAL**********/

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Fix this one day */

.bg-img {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508781015212-46d58946bb05?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=39b69f4b9e54ea449f90e3d714bf9215&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*********NAVIGATION*********/

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: /*rgba(255, 51, 0, .95);
 */
  z-index: 10;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 1em;
  }
}

.menu1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.menu2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 3;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 7vh;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.menu3 {
  grid-column: 4;
}

.menu4 {
  grid-column: 5;
}


/**************HOVER ANIMATION**************/

div>a {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

div>a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

div>a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

div>a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/**********MAIN HEADER***********/

header {
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/**********BODY*****************/

.Minfo {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.subtitle {
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-top: 29em;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtext {
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Centennial It's Academic</title>
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
    <header>
      <nav class="container">
        <div class="menu1">
          <a class="navLinks" href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu2">
          <a class="navLinks" href="#upcoming">Tournaments</a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <p>It's Academic</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu3">
          <a class="navLinks" href="#history">History</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu4">
          <a class="navLinks" href="#faq">Contact Info</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- This cluster  of info -->
      <div class="Minfo">
        <div class="subtitle">CENTENNIAL
          <br>
          <div class="title"> It's Academic</div>
          <br>
          <div class="subtext">Meets every Tuesday in Room 506</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>
    <!--Don't even -->

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/killerchef732/pen/gKmpwM) (Please open in full page mode):

An example of how I would want it to look is like on [this](https://chshackathon.github.io/) website, where all the info is under that background.

Comment: If you remove paddings from `.subtitle` - is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. There are 2 options in my mind:

1. Push the grid below the image. In this case, just move the `header` tag from `.bg-img` and put it after. 
   https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/ERWVdZ
2. You want the `fixed` effect (just like the website you attached). In this case, you need to use `position: fixed` on the header.
   https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/aKJvXW

   > The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport
   >   
   >   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position